# Extract data from hundreds of Microsoft Access databases

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, database, sql-server, merge

I have 1,371 Microsoft Access databases (.mdb), each database represents the daily log for a door entry system (so over 4 years worth of daily logs).

Within each mdb file there are only 2 tables: AlarmLog (which I am not interested in) and EventLog - this table contains each employee's use of an entry card, a typical day would create circa 1000 rows of data within this table.

My output request is simple: I need all of the entry data for the past 4 years in a single database/table/Excel etc so that it can be easily searched. Obviously I could go into each daily table, copy and paste into an Excel sheet but doing this 1,371 times would fill me with absolute dread. Using the Get External Data feature in Access only allows import from 1 database at a time also which would be painfully slow also.

I am not fussy as to which application is best to accomplish my task - Excel, Access, SQL etc - this is a one off job which will not be completed for another 4 years! Thanks

Comment: You can read mdb files with Powershell, making looping through all DBs and outputting to csv probably quite simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555625/read-data-from-mdb-files-using-powershell

Comment: Post a the important parts of your code here and mark it as the answer to help others with the same question.